# Can grep output only specified groupings that match?

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

Say I have a file:

```
# file: 'test.txt'
foobar bash 1
bash
foobar happy
foobar
```

I only want to know what words appear after "foobar", so I can use this regex:

```
"foobar \(\w\+\)"
```

The parenthesis indicate that I have a special interest in the word right after foobar.  But when I do a `grep "foobar \(\w\+\)" test.txt`, I get the entire lines that match the entire regex, rather than just "the word after foobar":

```
foobar bash 1
foobar happy
```

I would much prefer that the output of that command looked like this:

```
bash
happy
```

Is there a way to tell grep to only output the items that match the grouping (or a specific grouping) in a regular expression?

Comment: for those who do not need grep: `perl -lne 'print $1 if /foobar (\w+)/' < test.txt`

Comment: How come you need to escape the parentheses and `+` ?

Comment: To indicate a regex _grouping_ and to match _1 or more characters_ instead of searching for the actual characters `(`, `)`, and `+`.

Comment: @Sébastien You need `\(`, `\)`, `\+` in GRE. Use ERE = egrep, when you like `(`, `)`, `+`

Answer (score 635, accepted):

GNU grep has the `-P` option for perl-style regexes, and the `-o` option to print only what matches the pattern. These can be combined using look-around assertions (described under [Extended Patterns in the perlre manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)) to remove part of the grep pattern from what is determined to have matched for the purposes of `-o`.

```
$ grep -oP 'foobar \K\w+' test.txt
bash
happy
$
```

The `\K` is the short-form (and more efficient form) of `(?<=pattern)` which you use as a zero-width look-behind assertion before the text you want to output. `(?=pattern)` can be used as a zero-width look-ahead assertion after the text you want to output.

For instance, if you wanted to match the word between `foo` and `bar`, you could use:

```
$ grep -oP 'foo \K\w+(?= bar)' test.txt
```

or (for symmetry)

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=foo )\w+(?= bar)' test.txt
```

Comment: How you do it if your regex has more than a grouping? (as the title implied?)

Comment: @barracel:  I don't believe you can. Time for `sed(1)`

Comment: @camh I have just tested that `grep -oP 'foobar \K\w+' test.txt` outputs nothing with the OP's `test.txt`. The grep version is 2.5.1. What could be wrong ? O_O

Comment: @XichenLi: I can't say. I just built v2.5.1 of grep (it's pretty old - from 2006) and it worked for me.

Comment: @SOUser: I experienced the same - outputs nothing to file. I submitted the edit request to include '>' before the filename to send output as this worked for me.

Comment: Great answer for mentioning the `\K`! When I used `(?<=)` grep complained about my look-behind not being of fixed length, but using `\K` solved the problem.

Comment: seems -P flag doesn't work on Mac El Capitan at least

Comment: @OZZIE Does Mac El Capitan have GNU grep? I guess not (at least by default - perhaps you can install it with homebrew?)

Comment: This answer is OP--as in Over Powered :-D

Comment: @OZZIE Brew intall `ggrep`

Answer (score 152):

```
    sed -n "s/^.*foobar\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p"

-n     suppress printing
s      substitute
^.*    anything before foobar
foobar initial search match
\s*    any white space character (space)
\(     start capture group
\S*    capture any non-white space character (word)
\)     end capture group
.*$    anything after the capture group
\1     substitute everything with the 1st capture group
p      print it
```

Comment: +1 for the sed example, seems like a better tool for the job than grep.  One comment, the `^` and `$` are extraneous since `.*` is a greedy match.  However, including them might help clarify the intent of the regex.

Comment: And for me was escential to add `.*` at the beginning. Otherwise it also captured what's before to foobar.

Comment: For some reason this does not seem to work with macOS sed: `echo "foobar bash 1" | sed -n "s/^.*foobar\s*\(\S*\).*$/\1/p"` outputs nothing.

Comment: How do you do that when the search contains parenthesis?

Comment: I had to add "-r" as sed option in order for it to work.

Comment: @Frederik macOS is based off of BSD so many of the utilities are the BSD versions instead of the GNU ones.

Comment: with `sed -nr` and `( )` instead of `\( \)` it worked for me (Ubuntu 20.4)

Answer (score 74):

Standard grep can't do this, but [recent versions of GNU grep can](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match/13472#13472). You can turn to sed, awk or perl. Here are a few examples that do what you want on your sample input; they behave slightly differently in corner cases.

Replace `foobar word other stuff` by `word`, print only if a replacement is done.

```
sed -n -e 's/^foobar \([[:alnum:]]\+\).*/\1/p'
```

If the first word is `foobar`, print the second word.

```
awk '$1 == "foobar" {print $2}'
```

Strip `foobar` if it's the first word, and skip the line otherwise; then strip everything after the first whitespace and print.

```
perl -lne 's/^foobar\s+// or next; s/\s.*//; print'
```

Comment: Awesome!  I thought I may be able to do this with sed, but I haven't used it before and was hoping I could use my familiar `grep`.  But the syntax for these commands actually looks very familiar now that I am familiar with vim-style search & replace + regexes.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Not true, Gilles. See my answer for a GNU grep solution.

Comment: @camh: Ah, I didn't know GNU grep now had full PCRE support. I've corrected my answer, thanks.

Comment: This answer is especially useful for embedded Linux since Busybox `grep` doesn't have PCRE support.

Answer (score 51):

`pcregrep` has a smarter `-o` option
that lets you choose which capturing groups you want output. 
So, using your example file,

```
$ pcregrep -o1 "foobar (\w+)" test.txt
bash
happy
```

Comment: Wow, this was magical for me, thank you so much. I'm on MacOS, and was trying to use match-groups somehow. I had been trying `zegrep` because I was grepping a large zip-file, but also found that pcregrep will (from the`pcregrep --help` page):

`Files whose names end in .gz are read using zlib.`

So I could use it straight away on my zip file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 33):

Well, if you know that foobar is always the first word or the line, then you can use cut.  Like so:

```
grep "foobar" test.file | cut -d" " -f2
```

Comment: The `-o` switch on grep is widely implemented (moreso than the Gnu grep extensions), so doing `grep -o "foobar" test.file | cut -d" " -f2` will increase the effectiveness of this solution, which is more portable than using lookbehind assertions.

Comment: I believe that you would need `grep -o "foobar .*`" or `grep -o "foobar \w+"`.

Comment: Breaks if there is another space in the value

Answer (score 26):

Using `grep` is not cross-platform compatible, since `-P`/`--perl-regexp` is only available on [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html), not [BSD `grep`](https://man.openbsd.org/grep).

Here is the solution using [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```
$ rg -o "foobar (\w+)" -r '$1' <test.txt
bash
happy
```

---

As per `man rg`:

> `-r`/`--replace REPLACEMENT_TEXT` Replace every match with the text given.
>
> Capture group indices (e.g., `$5`) and names (e.g., `$foo`) are supported in the replacement string.

<sup>Related: [GH-462](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/462).</sup>

Comment: It is possible to install `gnugrep` on BSD distros however.

Answer (score 10):

If PCRE is not supported you can achieve the same result with two invocations of grep. For example to grab the word after *foobar* do this:

```
<test.txt grep -o 'foobar  *[^ ]*' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

This can be expanded to an arbitrary word after *foobar* like this (with EREs for readability):

```
i=1
<test.txt egrep -o 'foobar +([^ ]+ +){'$i'}[^ ]+' | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```

Output:

```
1
```

Note the index `i` is zero-based.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer of @jgshawkey very helpful. `grep` is not such a good tool for this, but sed is, although here we have an example that uses grep to grab a relevant line.

Regex syntax of sed is idiosyncratic if you are not used to it.

Here is another example: this one parses output of xinput to get an ID integer

```
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

and I want 19

```
export TouchPadID=$(xinput | grep 'TouchPad' | sed  -n "s/^.*id=\([[:digit:]]\+\).*$/\1/p")
```

Note the class syntax:

```
[[:digit:]]
```

and the need to escape the following `+`

I assume only one line matches.

Comment: Slightly simpler version without the extra `grep`, assuming 'TouchPad' is to the left of 'id' : `echo "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]" | sed -nE "s/.*TouchPad.+id=([0-9]+).*/\1/p"`

Answer (score 0):

*Compare Perl and Raku solutions:*

---

**Using Perl** (answers from @vault and @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'):

```perl
~$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /^foobar (\w+)/;'  file

#OR:

~$ perl -lne 's/^foobar\s+// or next; s/\s.*//; print'  file
```

---

**Using Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'put $0 if /^foobar \s+ (\w+)/;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne 's/^foobar\s+// or next; s/\s.*//; .put;'  file
```

A few more **Raku** answers (including Raku `grep`)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's/^foobar \s+ ( \S+ ) [ \s+ .*?]? $ /$0/ or next;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '.grep(/^foobar\s+/) or next; .words[1].put;'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne '$_ .= words; if .[0] eq "foobar" { put .[1] // next };'  file

#OR:

~$ raku -ne 'put .[1] || next if $_.=words[0] eq "foobar";'  file
```

Note: for the last few examples using indexing, stray spaces can be cleaned up *first* if they are problematic. Try using any of the various trim routines in Raku: `.trim`, `.trim-leading`. or `trim-trailing`, like so:

```perl
~$ raku -ne '.trim-trailing.grep(/foobar\s+/) or next; .words[1].put;'  file
```

*(Of course, an advantage of solutions in Perl/Raku is that these languages are cross-platform, having binaries available for Windows, etc.).*

---

*Perl References:*
https://perldoc.perl.org
https://www.perl.org

*Raku References:*
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org