# Using grep to match only a match group in a regular expression?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to set my keyboard layout with `setxkbmap` before launching Wine games, as I use Dvorak for typing and this breaks every game's controls. What I'd like to do is simply write a script that grabs the current keyboard layout before starting the game, stores it in a variable, then restores it after the game is done:

```
ORIGINAL_LAYOUT=`setxkbmap -query | grep -P 'layout\:\s{5}(\w+)'`
setxkbmap us
wine ...
setxkbmap $ORIGINAL_LAYOUT
```

The problem that I'm having is that grep matches the entire line and not just my capture group. Is there a way for me to simply dump the matched capture group?

For example, the output of `setxkbmap -query` is:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     dvorak
```

I'm interested in grabbing the layout.

Comment: You mean like `awk '/layout/ {print $2}'`?

Comment: See this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24722/returning-a-portion-of-a-line-matching-a-pattern/24725#24725

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can grep output only specified groupings that match?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this `awk` command:

```
setxkbmap -query | grep layout | awk '{print $2}'
```

or use `cut` command

`setxkbmap -query | grep layout | cut -d : -f2`

Comment: The `grep` is unnecessary, see jasonwryan's comment to the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-o` and change the grep a little bit

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print  only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such
          part on a separate output line.
```

.

```
ORIGINAL_LAYOUT=`setxkbmap -query | grep -oP '(?<=layout\:\s{5})\w+'`
```

We changed the regex to use a look-behind so its not part of the match

Comment: This would have returned the full line, not the part between parentheses.

Comment: @Lekensteyn This is why you modify the regex to use look-behind...

Comment: Include that in your answer then. Nifty trick btw, it never occured to me to use lookbehind in `grep`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn advice taken

Comment: Note: ```-P``` is not supported since OSX Lion and on BSD grep