# Opposite of \K, to keep the stuff right

Tags: grep, regular-expression, perl

On the [`perlre`'s extended patterns page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) we can read about `\K`:

> Keep the stuff left of the `\K`, don't include it in $&

Here is the practical example using GNU `grep` (which actually keeps stuff right of the `\K`):

```
$ echo "foo bar buzz" | grep -Po "foo \Kbar buzz"
bar buzz
```

Is there any opposite sequence of `\K`?

For example to print just `bar`, like:

```
$ echo "foo bar buzz" | grep -Po "foo \Kbar\X buzz"
bar
```

Comment: Is sed also valid? `echo "foo bar buzz" | sed -E '/foo (bar) buzz/s//\1/'`

Comment: @isaac I don't see anything in that duplicate that answers the question here.

Comment: @roaima The [first answer in there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13472/265604) presents the same zero-width lookahead (?=...) `grep -oP 'foo \K\w+(?= bar)' test.txt` that the **accepted** answer use here. It seems to me that the answer there also solve the issue here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case, [zero-width lookahead `(?=...)` does what you want](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions):

```
$ echo foo bar buzz | grep -Po "foo \Kbar(?= buzz)"
bar
```

It does require some extra parentheses. There is no single-character escape for lookahead the way there is for `\K`.

`\K` is really just a zero-width lookbehind for everything so far, so this is also equivalent to

```
echo foo bar buzz | grep -Po "(?<=foo )bar(?= buzz)"
```

which I find easier to follow personally.

Comment: IIRC the difference between `pat\K` and `(?<=pat)` is that `\K` permits variable-length lookbehind - AFAIK there's no such restriction for the lookahead version (which is perhaps why there's no lookahead equivalent of `\K`)

Comment: That's my understanding as well, and that it can be more efficient than regular lookbehind (because there's no extra backtracking?), so it can be preferable sometimes.

Comment: To demonstrate the difference, `echo foooooo bar | grep -oP "(?<=foo+) \Kbar"` will fail, while `$ echo foooooo bar | grep -oP "foo+ \Kbar"
bar` will yield `bar`.