# Find variable names in a template file using Bash/Sed/Awk?

Tags: bash, sed

I have some template files which I'm currently processing with envsubst, which works great.

```
<?php

$config['db_host'] = '${DB_HOST}';
$config['db_port'] = '${DB_PORT}';
$config['url'] = 'http://${WEB_HOST}/${WEB_PATH}';

// Please do NOT change this value
$config['maxSize'] = 25;
```

What I'm trying to find is a way to scan the file with a bash script and generate a list of all the environment variables that need to be set, so I can then dump them into a .env file like so:

```
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
WEB_HOST=
WEB_PATH=
```

I think it's possible with sed, however all of the examples I've found after 30 minutes of googling have been about how to replace variables inline, and nothing about just printing out the matches.

Comment: Are all variables enclosed in braces?  Are they the only uppercase words in the file?

Comment: Yes, they're all uppercase and enclosed, the only special character would be an underscore.

Comment: "They're all uppercase" =/= they are **the only** uppercase

Comment: Ahh I see what you meant.  No, some of the non-variablized config lines have uppercase characters in them, and that explains the results when I tried your awk.  Let me update my original example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your criteria seems to be: match any number of uppercase letters or underscores contained between `${` and `}`.

`gawk` can work for this on it's own, or `grep` can simplify the pattern matching part (but will need extra formatting afterwards).

---

### GNU `awk`:

```bsh
gawk -v 'RS=[$]{' -F '}' '$1 ~ /^[A-Z_]+$/ && !a[$1]++ {printf "%s=\n", $1}' FILE
```

- GNU awk can accept a regex for the record separator, so by assigning `RS=[$]{`, it will split the input `FILE` up into records wherever the pattern `${` appears
- field separator set to `}` – now the first field of each record can be checked to see if it matches your other criteria: nothing other than one-or-more of `[A-Z_]`
- using `&& !a[$1]++` will remove duplicates
- the print statement adds an equals sign `=` to the end of each line – to match your desired output
- also note: the first part of a file will always be counted as the first record – even if it didn't begin with `${` – this means that if your file began with `[A-Z_]+}` (unlikely) – those uppercase letters/underscores would "match" and be printed on the first line of output

---

### `grep` + formatting

`grep` is perhaps easier to understand (thanks to it's `-o` / `--only-matching` option):

```bsh
grep -o '${[A-Z_]\+}' FILE
```

- but this doesn't format the output: a pipe through `sed` could do that: eg.

```bsh
grep -o '${[A-Z_]\+}' FILE | sed 's/${\(.*\)}/\1=/'
```

- this doesn't remove duplicates: pipe output through `sort -u` to do that, or alternatively pipe once through awk:

```bsh
grep -o '${[A-Z_]\+}' FILE | awk -F '[{}]' '!a[$0]++{printf "%s=\n", $2}'
```

Comment: Thank you!  I went with grep+awk, as gawk isn't currently installed on my build machine and I wanted to keep the requirements to a minimum.

Comment: How to make logical expression with `find` and `||`, if there is at least one such variable?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
cat file | grep -o '${\w*}' | sed -e 's|${||g' -e 's|}|=|g'

DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
WEB_HOST=
WEB_PATH=
```

Which seems to work well enough even if it's not pretty!

Or another method (modified from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13467/229729):

```
cat file | sed -n -e 's/.*${\(\w\+\)}.*/\1=/p'
```

Comment: `cat file | sed stuff` can be replaced with `sed stuff file`

Comment: This is true, however when you're writing/testing a regex it's easier to edit stuff at the end of the line than the beginning :)

Comment: @jwh Your second sed command will only find the last `${<match>}` on each line: it matches `${WEB_PATH}`, but in doing so skips `${WEB_HOST}`